# Ubuntu 13.04 doesn't automount razr d1 mtp

Tags: 13.04, mtp

My Ubuntu 13.04 is not auto-mounting my Motorola Razr D1. I have installed mtpfs with no luck.

What else should I do to be able to mount and copy my awesome MP3 files in it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This did it for me and my nexus7 and nexus4 : http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1773598

But I personally do like AirDroid : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid&hl=en

no need for any drivers, just have your laptop talk to the phone through the browser.